# How to Encrypt and Sign e-mail using PHP mailer?

Tags: php, email, encryption

I'd like to be able to send e-mail to clients via a web app using PHPMailer and do the following.  I think I know how to sign with my certificate with the built-in functions in PHPMailer:

```
$mail->sign("/pathto/sign_cert_file", "/pathto/sign_key_file", "password", "/pathto/sign_extracerts_file");
```

That works even sending via SMTP which I what I want to do and which I am  doing.

However, I would like to also send encrypted messages to recipients.  Is there a way to do that and how is that done within PHPMailer?  Does that require that the user has their own e-mail certificate and that you encrypt the message using their public key ?  You would have to have a library of public keys for the users ?  How would that be done ?

If found this post: [Send encrypted email using certificates in PHP](http://cyberstarweb.com/send-encrypted-email-using-certificates-in-php/)

that maybe indicates how to actually encrypt the message also.  Any help with that ?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I did find a reference for encrypting e-mail with the recipient's public key, cert.pem using PHPMailer.  It basically adds a class method for encryption and you just call that with the users public key.  It does work.  BTW, is the question posted, or is it still being held for approval or editing ?

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps this is one way using PHP and GPG:

[Encrypting Email with GPG](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch14_12.htm)

although you do need a public key for the recipient.